# magic square with prime numbers of any order

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, syntax, prime-numbers

how could you create a script in Mathematica that generates magic squares of order n, but that the numbers that form the square are all primes

I've looked at what's in other answers but I can not think of anything

Comment: it's not that easy you know... http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeMagicSquare.html

Comment: http://www.magic-squares.net/primesqr.htm#A